# Laplace Transform of e^{-at}

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, exponential-function, laplace-transform

I have some trouble understanding the Laplace Transform of 
$x(t) = e^{-at}u(t)$, where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. When calculating the integral, we get to a point where
$$ X(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a+s)t} \,dt = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{-1}{a + s} \left[e^{-(a + s)T} - 1\right]$$
Here we say that the Laplace Transfrom exists for $$-(a+s) < 0 \Rightarrow s > -a$$
a is a constant which can either a real or a complex number. s is a complex number for sure. How can we compare these 2? If a is real, how can we say that $$ complex > real$$ Because technically that is what we are implying when we say s > -a. Same goes for complex numbers. How can we say $$complex1 > complex2$$
Am I missing something?

Comment: It is for $\Re(a+s) >0$ then $\lim_{T \to \infty}|e^{-(a+s)T}| =\lim_{T \to \infty} e^{-\Re(a+s)  T} = 0$ so that $X(s) = \frac1{a+s}$. For $\Re(a+s) < 0$  the integral diverges. Now sometimes the Laplace transform is introduced before a good understanding of complex analytic functions so they may restrict to $a,s$ real (note $X(s)$ is uniquely defined by its restriction to $s \in \Bbb{R} $)

Comment: That's true, but we are trying to calculate $e^{-(a+s)}T$ as T \to \infty, not its modulus

Comment: I have shown it $\to 0$

Comment: @AndrewSpan $|a_n| \to 0 \iff a_n \to 0$ so Reun's proof is sufficient

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification guys. @Brevan Ellefsen, I didn't know that was true for complex functions as well. I thought it worked only for sequences and functions. Is there a theorem about this? (the fact that iff the modulus of a complex function converges to 0, so does the complex function.)

Comment: @AndrewSpan if you know it holds for real functions, just consider the real and imaginary parts of your complex function. It's just a result about limits from real analysis; if your function is continuous at a point then the limit there must equal the limit of any subsequence. Thus the result for real sequences implies the real function version which implies the complex function version.

Comment: @AndrewSpan I would have to check, but I assume the result holds more generally anywhere we have a norm defined, which would be proved via epsilon-delta with a little work. The same intuition carries over; norms are positive definite so we have $|x| = 0 \iff x = 0$. This definitely holds for metric spaces.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yes that makes sense. Thanks a lot for explaining